# Not able to load css

Tags: java, css, struts-1

I have my css file placed over here : C:\Test Workspace\MySunlifeApp\cssFiles.

In one of the jsp s of my application named MySunlifeApp, i want to load this css file.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>Calendar</title>
  <h1><div align="center">My Sunlife App</div></h1>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/MySunlifeApp/cssFiles/BackgroundIMGE.css" />

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

   <script  type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">


   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();


  });
  </script>


</head>
```

But when i am running it, i am getting an error :GET http://localhost:8090/MySunlifeApp/cssFiles/BackgroundIMGE.css NewCalendar.jsp:12

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: The error 404 itself says resource not found, could you post your application structure, I'm sure this file is not present in your application.

Comment: @RahulYadav My css file is present at C:\Test Workspace\MySunlifeApp\cssFiles and the jsp which is trying to use it is present at C:\Test Workspace\MySunlifeApp\WebContent

Comment: Could you post your project structure, so that I can guide you along?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
href="./MySunlifeApp/cssFiles/BackgroundIMGE.css"
```

and the h1 element should be inside body tag.

```
 <!doctype html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Calendar</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./MySunlifeApp/cssFiles/BackgroundIMGE.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
    <h1><div align="center">My Sunlife App</div></h1>

     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

       <script  type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">


       $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();


      });
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

## Best Practice

Always keep the css in the head and js scripts before closing the body tag.

Comment: Getting same error. Maybe i can fix it if i know where exactly this path refers? http://localhost:8090/

Comment: are you using any server like xampp

Comment: i am using tomcat v7.0

Answer (score 0):

Add relative path of your css file from your jsp path.

For example if your jsp file and the cssFiles folder in the same directory you can add
`href="cssFiles/BackgroundIMGE.css"`

you can use `../` to access the direct parent folder.

According to it you can give the relative path to the css file from your jsp file.

Comment: If you give me your jsp path I'll give you the relative path for the css file.

Comment: it is somehow not giving me any error but also not loading the background image which the css file has. The code of my css is                                                body {
background-image: url(C:\Test Workspace\MySunlifeApp\cssFiles\asd.jpg); /*You will specify your image path here.*/

-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-position: top center !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background-attachment: fixed;
}   I am not sure what will be url of image.

Comment: use this path for access your css file <link href="../cssFiles/BackgroundIMGE.css"/> use this for image url (asd.jpg) and let me know if it worked